# The general expression of the possibility of n events union?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence

Suppose all the events are independent.

$P(A \cup B \cup C)= P(A) + P(B) + P(C)- P(AB) - P(AC) - P(BC) + P(ABC)$

When there are $N$ events together, what's the general expression of the possibility?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<\dots<i_k\leq n}\mathbb{P}(A_{i_1}\cap\dots\cap A_{i_k})$$

This is sometimes called the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 0):

It all the events are independent, then a possible expression is $$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1-\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^C\right)=  1- \prod_{i=1}^n  \mathbb{P}(A_i^C)$$ $$=  1- \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1- \mathbb{P}(A_i)\right)$$